# Exception "Texture cannot be null" Direct X

Tags: c++, exception, null, directx, textures

I am coding a 2D Game using DirectX11 and DirectXTK.

I did a class Framework that initializes both the window displayed for the game and initializes DirectX. These initializations work correctly. Then, I decided to draw some backgrounds, etc in the window, but after a while it exits on an exception. I did a try{ ... } catch(){ } block, which tells me that "Texture cannot be null". However, i could not find which texture it is talking about, even by debbugging and checking all the values.

I decided to separate the different elements i was drawing in the window, to see where the problem might come from... So now i have 3 draw methods :

```
Draw(DWORD &elapsedTime);
DrawBackground(DWORD &elapsedTime);
DrawCharacter(DWORD &elapsedTime);
```

The Draw(DWORD &elapsedTime) method calls both DrawBackground() and DrawCharacter() methods.

Here is my Draw Method :

```
void Framework::Draw(DWORD * elapsedTime)
{
    // Clearing the Back Buffer
    immediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, Colors::Aquamarine);

    //Clearing the depth buffer to max depth (1.0)
    immediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0); //immediateContext is a ID3D11DeviceContext*

    CommonStates states(d3dDevice); //d3dDevice is a ID3D11Device*

    sprites.reset(new SpriteBatch(immediateContext));


    sprites->Begin(SpriteSortMode_Deferred, states.NonPremultiplied());

    DrawBackground1(elapsedTime);
    DrawCharacter(elapsedTime);

    sprites->End();


    //Presenting the back buffer to the front buffer
    swapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

By debugging i am almost sure that the exception comes from both DrawBackground() and DrawCharacter(). Indeed, when I comment those in the Draw method, i have no error, but as soon as i put one it sets the exception after displaying what i want during a few seconds.

Here is the method DrawBackground() for example :

```
void Framework::DrawBackground1(DWORD * elpasedTime)
{
    RECT *try1 = new RECT();
    try1->bottom = 0; try1->left = 0; try1->right = (int)WIDTH; try1->bottom = (int)HEIGHT;


    ID3D11ShaderResourceView * texture2 = nullptr;
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView * textureRV = nullptr;

    CreateDDSTextureFromFile(d3dDevice, L"../Images/backgrounds/set2_background.dds", nullptr, &textureRV);
    CreateDDSTextureFromFile(d3dDevice, L"../Images/backgrounds/set3_tiles.dds", nullptr, &texture2);

    sprites->Draw(textureRV, XMFLOAT2(0, 0), try1, Colors::White);
    sprites->Draw(texture2, XMFLOAT2(0, 0), try1, Colors::CornflowerBlue);
}
```

So as soon as i uncomment this method (or any DrawCharacter(), which follows the same steps), the window displays what i expect it to for a few seconds, but then i get the exception "Texture cannot be null". I also noticed that the method DrawCharacter() lets the window displaying what i want longer than the method DrawBackground(), whose texture is way bigger than the character's one.

I'm not sure if this information is useful but i think that maybe this might be linked to the size of the texture ?

Would you notice anything that i did wrong in this code ? Why would a texture be considered null while it does display it for a while ? I've been looking for answers for a few hours now, some help would be amazing please !
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you create two new ID3D11ShaderResourceView every iteration without Release-ing the old ones. You could try by creating the ShaderResourceViews only once and storing them as global variables, or you could try by ->Release() them after the sprites->Draw(...) calls.

Comment: Thank you !! I was about to do an edit saying that i found out it was because we are loading the textures all the time, and the error was  because we do exceed the memory of the system because of that. I was about to set the textures as global variables and it does work now, thank you for your help !!

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful. Can I just inform you to still Release your ID3D11ShaderResourceView and other COM Objects when your application terminates if you haven't already. If you don't know why you should read [this section about COM on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff637359(v=vs.85).aspx).